Printf stops working (sends garbage data) when transitioning from C to C++ for STM32l433 board
I've been working on a Nucleo STM32L433RCP and had a great setup where I had a custom _write function that took characters buffered by printf and transmitted them over a UART. All of it was written in C and worked wonderfully. I have since transitioned to C++ for compatibility with a group I'm working on a project in, and it doesn't work anymore. printf will still call the write function on a flush, but the buffer is filled with garbage as far as I can tell. I am working bare-metal, and not using the STM32CubeIDE or the HAL tools it comes with.
The only changes I've made while switching between C and C++ are having _write and my reset handler be run as C code using extern "C" (without which, nothing happens).
Below is my main.cpp, please ignore some uglier formatting

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define GPIOBS 0x48000400

#define RCC_APB2ENR 0x4002104C
// #define ODR 0x14
// #define OTR 0x04

#define SERIAL_PORT "/dev/ttyACM0"
#include "../bsp/stm32l433xx.h"

uint32_t SystemCoreClock = 0;
extern uint32_t _sidata, _sdata, _edata, _sbss, _ebss;

uint32_t arr[2000];

extern "C" {
// Reset handler: set the stack pointer and branch to main().
__attribute__((naked)) void reset_handler(void) {
  // Set the stack pointer to the 'end of stack' value.
  __asm__("LDR r0, =_estack\n\t"
          "MOV sp, r0");
  // Branch to main().
  __asm__("B main");
}
}



extern "C" {

int __io_putchar(int ch){
  while (!(USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_TXE)) {};
  USART2->TDR = ch;
  return ch;
}

int _write(int handle, const char* data, int size) {
  int count = size;
  while (count--) {
    __io_putchar(*data++);
  }
  while (!(USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_TXE)) {};
  USART2->TDR = 74;
  while (!(USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_TXE)) {};
  USART2->TDR = 10;
  while (!(USART2->ISR & USART_ISR_TXE)) {};
  USART2->TDR = 13;
  return size;
} 




void init(){
  // copy the flash varibales into ram
  memcpy(&_sdata, &_sidata, 4*(&_edata - &_sdata));
  // Clear the .bss section in RAM.
  memset(&_sbss, 0x00, 4* (&_ebss -&_sbss));
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i){
    arr[i] = i;
  }
  // Enable floating-point unit.
  SCB->CPACR |= (0xF << 20);
  RCC->AHB2ENR |= 7;

  // Enable floating-point unit.
  SCB->CPACR |= (0xF << 20);
  // Default clock source is the "multi-speed" internal oscillator.
  // Switch to the 16MHz HSI oscillator.
  RCC->CR |= (RCC_CR_HSION);
  while (!(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSIRDY)) {
  };
  RCC->CFGR &= ~(RCC_CFGR_SW);
  RCC->CFGR |= (RCC_CFGR_SW_HSI);
  while ((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_HSI) {
  };
  SystemCoreClock = 16000000;

  RCC->APB1ENR1 |= (RCC_APB1ENR1_USART2EN);
  RCC->AHB2ENR |= (RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOAEN);
  // Configure pins A2, A15 for USART2 (AF7, AF3).
  GPIOA->MODER &= ~((0x3 << (2 * 2)) | (0x3 << (15 * 2)));
  GPIOA->MODER |= ((0x2 << (2 * 2)) | (0x2 << (15 * 2)));
  GPIOA->OTYPER &= ~((0x1 << 2) | (0x1 << 15));
  GPIOA->OSPEEDR &= ~((0x3 << (2 * 2)) | (0x3 << (15 * 2)));
  GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= ((0x2 << (2 * 2)) | (0x2 << (15 * 2)));
  GPIOA->AFR[0] &= ~((0xF << (2 * 4)));
  GPIOA->AFR[0] |= ((0x7 << (2 * 4)));
  GPIOA->AFR[1] &= ~((0xF << ((15 - 8) * 4)));
  GPIOA->AFR[1] |= ((0x3 << ((15 - 8) * 4)));

  uint16_t uartdiv = SystemCoreClock / 9600;

  USART2->BRR = uartdiv;
  USART2->CR1 |= (USART_CR1_RE | USART_CR1_TE | USART_CR1_UE);
  
  //printf("starting, Clock speed is: %lu \r\n", SystemCoreClock);

  //  LED Test

  GPIOB->MODER &= (~(1 << 27));
  GPIOB->MODER |= (1 << 26);
  GPIOB->ODR |= (1 << 13);
  printf("Test\n");
}
}


int main() {
  init();
  int x = 0;
  ;
  while (1) {
    GPIOB->ODR |= (1 << 13);
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    };
    GPIOB->ODR &= (~(1 << 13));
    for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    };
    x++;
    printf("APPLE\n");// %d\r\n", x);
    _write(0, "APE TOGETHER",12);
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}

Currently I have my _write function also outputting a newline and carriage return so it's less abyssmal to look at when viewing the output over uart. I've tested everything in C and it works.
I'm compiling using arm-none-eabi-g++/gcc depending on if it's a C file or not.
Thank you

What optimization level are you passing to the C++ compiler?  I see a lot of risky code that could be removed by an optimising pass, you might like to check the assembly listing.

No optimization level (don't have a -O), so shouldn't be losing anything to optimization besides any differences between g++ and gcc

@Jarod42 that while loop is there to wait until the TXE is 0, so it's not infinite, it's just doing nothing while TXE is high

Check all hardware mapped variables are volatile.

@RichardCritten all of the actual hardware variables are volatile, as definied in the many header files I pull them from

Good time to see if you have a JTAG debugger you can use to snoop in. Side note: Absolutely no shame in calling a C module from C++ if the code works in C and not C++.

Random observation: char can be signed or unsigned, and that changes the semantics of __io_putchar(*data++). Explicitly casting the argument is safer.

Is your stack big enough?  Does increasing the stack size make any difference?

What is sizeof(unsigned long)? If it is different(larger) from sizeof(unsigned), you have some UB in format string. Use digit count format ("%10u") instead of "%lu". It would be better if C++23 <print> or open source {fmt} were available instead of C printf, but on embedded environments, that might be not possible.

Your C/C++ runtime start-up is inadequate.  It simply establishes a stack and jumps to main().  It must do other things to establish a full run-time environment that is expected of both the C and C++ runtime, and it should normally be done before main(), the expectation being that in main() the runtime environment is already complete.
Some of those things you are doing in init() albeit from rather than before main().  For example you appear to be performing static initialisation of .data and .bss segments, but for C++ that is insufficient.  You also need to iterate through static constructors, and prior to that there will likely be some C library initialisation that needs to be called to establish stdin, stdout, stderr and a heap for example.
Some of the things that should be done (normally from __start before main):

Initializing global and static memory (you are already doing that part in main()).
C++ global objects must be constructed. The linker places these constructors into the .init, .init_array, or .ctors section of the image.
Prepare the argc and argv variables for invoking main (even if it’s just setting these to 0/NULL).
Perform any additional setup steps required by the C/C++ standard library implementation.

Additional runtime initialisation steps may be required depending on the application and run-time environment, such as:

Heap initialization
Initialize stdio (i.e., stdin, stdout, stderr)
Initialize exception support (if using C++)
Register destructors and other cleanup functions that will run when exiting the program (using atexit and __cxa_atexit)
Prepare environment variables.
RTOS initialisation.

You would do well to take a provided C/C++ runtime start-up and adapt it to your platform's needs than to take your rather minimalist approach that is clearly not establishing a suitable environment for a full C or C++ runtime.
For your part you would at least perhaps link the CMSIS core_cm4.c, startup_stm32l433xx.s and system_stm32l4xx.c  which include most of the start-up and initialisation code you will need or need to adapt.  These are ARM specified CMSIS start-up code and not STM32 HAL code, they largely address core Cortex M4 features and ST's specific PLL configuration and external memory configuration (if used).  I'd recommend also using stm32l4xx_it.c for basic exception handlers (which you should probably elaborate).
The easiest way to obtain the STM32L4xx CMSIS perhaps is to install the STM32Cube support and copy the installed CMSIS layer to your project.  It is all source code and independent of STM32Cube and critically is not related to either of STM32 HAL or LL layers or even the older standard peripheral library (SPL).

I wrote some advice for how to write a CRT here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47940277/584518
